# Shouldn't MVC be MCV?

Tags: mvc

The model is defined first, then the controllers are fired based on the user request, and they will generate the views (the output).

So it should be M->C->V, right?

Comment: Agreed, I've always found this a little puzzling when I first heard about MVC.

Comment: maybe it's in order of importance: Model is the most important, View is how the end-user sees the model and Controller just binds the 2 toghether

Comment: I guess MVC sounds nicer than MCV

Answer (score 7):

Because that's how the originator of the term ordered it.

"MVC was first described in 1979[3] by Trygve Reenskaug, then working on Smalltalk at Xerox PARC."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it comes down to dependancies and usage?  Each item on the right knows about or uses  the item on the left.  Controller knows about views and models.  Views know about Models.  Models just know about themselves.  So hence the naming convention MVC.  Just my thoughts.

Comment: It could also be, you know, just because.

Comment: @KevinWang "Ours is not to question why.  Ours is but to do and try"...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this should be MCV but many acronyms are made in wrong order just because they sound better that way.

```
AmVeeSee  (more fluent) 
AmSeeVee  (less fluent)
```